# Add different commits from a single branch to different branches

Tags: git, github

Newbie question:

I made 3 commits to `master` branch, instead of opening 3 new branches for the changes (they were in different contexts).

What is the easiest way to cherry-pick specific commits and apply them to a new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start 3 branches from `master~3`, in order to begin before the three incorrect commits:

```
git checkout -b fix1 master~3
git cherry-pick master~2

git checkout -b fix2 master~3
git cherry-pick master~1

git checkout -b fix3 master~3
git cherry-pick master
```

(Assuming the three commits were `fix1`, `fix2` and `fix3`, from oldest `master~2` to most most recent `master` SHA1 commit)

Then you can reset master (provided you did not push it already, or if you are alone working on master)

```
git checkout master
git reset hard @~3
```

Comment: @goelakash you can or you actually can reference them directly: `git cherry-pick master` for `fix1`, `git cherry-pick master~1` for `fix2`, and `git cherry-pick master~2` for `fix3`.

Comment: @goelakash I used the manual approach in my answer because you mentioned "I copied the SHA codes of the last 3 commits in a text file"

Comment: Thanks. My gripe was with the manual copying. This should speed things a lot.